# Does singular value decomposition join with $LU$ and $QR$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

[image: Linear Algebra and Its Applications by Gilbert Strang]

I was confused when I saw the above because I couldn't find exactly what this meant. I've heard that there are ways to calculate SVD using $LU$ or $QR$ decomposition, but I don't know if it's related to both. Is there a good explanation for this?

Comment: Don’t take “joins with” too seriously. I don’t see a clear connection between the SVD and LU or QR factorizations. There is something called the “QR algorithm” which is different than QR factorization and which is used to compute eigenvalues. That QR algorithm is probably relevant for computing the SVD numerically.